# Are beer/wine enthusiasts encouraged to ask questions that aren't necessarily about brewing?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we want to encourage enthusiasts of beer / wine to ask questions that aren't specifically about brewing?

The FAQ says the site is for `dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts`, but not whether they are enthusiasts of the process or the product.

I can picture some "product enthusiast" questions being about the brewing process (e.g. 'Why does XYZ taste different from ABC?'), but whether it's about the brewing process may not be apparent until the question is answered.

An example may be, "What has caused the price of XYZ product to trend upwards faster than ABC product?".  Whether or not the question is appropriate depends on the answer - it could be a shortage of an ingredient in XYZ, an improvement in the brewing process of ABC, or it could be an environmental or political factor.

Does the "serious enthusiast" label extend to product & industry related questions?  Or is our focus exclusively on the process?

Comment: I've been curious about this as well.  Some food pairing questions have been asked, but there's definite gray area between that and the cooking stackexchange.   I have also wondered about things like appropriate glassware.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the "serious enthusiasts" section should lead us to discuss subject matter that affects the enjoyment of our finished product.

eg 
 I have made a Citra Pale what food should I pair with it?

What shape/size glass should a dark barley wine be best consumed in?

These to me are all relevant to the craft of a home brewer/wine maker displaying their wears to the best of their ability. The pursuit of a perfect pint does not end with the draining of a fermenter into a bottle, it ends with a hopefully enjoyable experience shared with friends and family.

Comment: I disagree based on the [seasoned advice on-topic document](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which states that flavor pairings are off topic. While this is not that site, I think we should strive to be similar, at least. On the other hand 'Brewed beverage appreciation' *is* on topic here so I think shape and size of the glass is on topic.

Comment: @Mr_road all the questions you mention is beer-related and interesting. However, the standard should not be put that low in my opinion, since such questions only to a very limited degree relates to choices you make in the brewing / production process. There are other fora for consumers and connoisseurs, like for instance [https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/).